# Python: replicate Matlab's generateMesh function

Tags: python, matlab, mesh, triangulation, finite-element-analysis

I am in the process of converting a codebase from Matlab to Python and noticed that [`generateMesh`](https://it.mathworks.com/help/pde/ug/generate-mesh.html) gets called on some polygons before carrying out a finite element analysis.

What I need to get as an output is a list of all the elements and nodes, with their respective coordinates. I don't need any GUI, just the output nodes and elements information.

The best solution I came across is [something like this](https://bthierry.pages.math.cnrs.fr/tutorial/gmsh/api_detail/) done with gmsh. I know gmsh is a pretty big library and I am afraid it might be a little too much for my needs. Is there any other package you'd suggest?

Triangular meshes are fine for the moment, but I would like the package to support tetrahedral meshes as well in case it's needed in the future.

Thank you

**edit**: I forgot to mention that I am only dealing with 2D geometries, as the triangular and tetrahedral elements imply.